# How to update and query registry using batch file through php

Tags: php

I am using batch file to add and query the windows registry as below:
Below is to add the value in registry I name this as write.bat

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\SpecialAccounts\UserList" /f /v "MyCustomWorkgroupUsername" /t REG_DWORD /d 4
```

Below is to query the value in registry I name this as read.bat

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\SpecialAccounts\UserList" /v
 MyCustomWorkgroupUsername') do (set /a num = %%a )

 echo %num% > "d:\\temp\\val.txt"
```

I am querying and writing the value in val.txt.

Below is the php code:

```
<?php
$writeReg = "D:\\reg\\write.bat";
$readReg = "D:\\reg\\read.bat";
write_reg($writeReg);
read_reg($readReg);
function write_reg($writeReg)
{
    system($writeReg);
    echo "Done";
}
function read_reg($readReg)
{
    system($readReg);
    echo "Done";
}

?>
```

If I run just the batch file its working fine but when I run through php, I am unable to add the value. Please help me what is wrong here.